# How to logout and login to Ubuntu runing on VirtualBox

Tags: kubuntu, virtualbox, login, logout

I logged out from my Ubuntu VM and then I got the black screen as below. There is no option to log back-in to the machine.

The only option I have is to restart the VM which I don't want.

Is there a way to log out from Ubuntu VM and login?
I am using Oracle VirtualBox

[image]

Comment: Did this happen after installing the VirtualBox Additions? 

Comment: Try to press <RIghtCtrl> and then <F3> to see 3rd tty.

Comment: @matigo, not sure. I have been using this more than a year now but never tried logging out. Experiencing this for the first time.

Comment: @N0rbert, tried your suggestion but no luck. Its like Hanged. Seems like restart VM is the only option.

Comment: Uptime for the VM is over a year? That's a little more reliable than the average person sees with VirtualBox 

Comment: No no, not the uptime. I mean, I shut it down when I am done and start again when I wanna work. Never tried to logout and login again.